# NestedScrollView not working correctly with RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a layout where there's a toolbar on top, then a `NestedScrollView` right after. The toolbar works fine, however, the `NestedScrollView` partially works. Inside this view, I have a `LinearLayout` that contains both an included layout and a recycler view. Everything works fine, however, the recyler view when scrolled will scroll within the recycler view and not the outer scroll. Once the first item of the recyclerview has been scrolled, then the it starts the outer scroll and I can't see the layout on top anymore. Here's my code:

Edit: Playing with it a bit, it seems like when I go back to the previous page and then click on this fragment again, I don't see the recyclerview contents anymore

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.base.core.QuestionFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/questionContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="10dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
                app:title="Question"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.BoldText"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/question"
                layout="@layout/item_question"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/commentRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_comments" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe this article can help you 
https://momen-zaq.medium.com/recyclerview-with-nestedscrollview-best-practices-and-how-to-avoid-it-152fd9ce46d9